Next.js Vercel Deployment Error: Failed to Collect Page Data for /api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId]
I'm trying to deploy my Next.js application to Vercel, but I'm encountering a build error related to a specific API route. The error message indicates that there was a failure in collecting page data for /api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId], and the build process exits with code 1. Below is the relevant part of the error log:
Error message:
  at fa (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:33:69)
    at new t (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:131:739)
    at 13543 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId]/route.js:1:3921)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 91782 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId]/route.js:1:2942)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 40100 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId]/route.js:1:1267)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at t (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId]/route.js:1:4006)
    at /vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId]/route.js:1:4041 {
  clientVersion: '5.16.2',
  errorCode: undefined
}
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/favourites/[drivingSchoolId]
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1268:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1


I also faced the exact same issue. I am using Prisma for querying DB and that is why API route failed.
If you are using prisma, change build command in vercel project settings as follows

On Dashboard, Click on your project
Click on Settings Tab
under Build & Development Settings override Build command to npx prisma generate && next build
Redeploy the app

